# Navigation drawer with static and dynamic menu items

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I am new to android and trying to create a Navigation drawer using [this](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html).

To show menu items in left drawer, I am doing this

```
DrawerLayout  mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

List<DataItems> myTest = myDbAdapter.getValuesFromDb(); // method in DbAdapter class 
                                                       // to get records from db.

// Pass the data to ListView adapter
MyNavigationDrawerAdapter adapter = new MyNavigationDrawerAdapter(
   this, 
   R.layout.drawer_listview_item, 
   myTest);

// Set the adapter for the list view
mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);
```

It is working fine, but I want to add couple of static values in Navigation drawer that always remains the same, and after those values I want to show the value taken from database.

I have searched almost everywhere but could not find any solution for this.

Comment: add items manually to List<DataItems> myTest

Comment: You mean after `List<DataItems> myTest = myDbAdapter.getValuesFromDb();`   
I can manually add items by doing this:
`myTest.add(...); // but this takes DataItems`

Comment: so what's the problem? You don't have DataItems.java? create object  and add values to it.

Comment: Thanks, by manually adding it to my list I am able to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

The ArrayAdapter you are using is a simple way to to create a list of different strings from an array. But it is also constrained to only do that. Depending on your need there is different ways. What I see you have two options. Either change the values in the database and keep going for a single TextView. Or if you want a more advanced list you should create a new class that expands a BaseAdapter. And set your adapter to this instead.

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
    Context mCtx;
    List<DataItems> mData;

    public MyAdapter(Context context, List<DataItems> myTest) {
    mCtx = context;
    mData = myTest;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mData.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ItemHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = new ItemHolder().getView();
        }
        holder = convertView.getTag();
        holder.update(mData.get(position).toString());
        return holder.getView();
    }

    private class ItemHolder {
        LinearLayout layout;
        TextView txt;

        public ItemHolder() {
            layout = View.inflate(mCtx, R.layout.item, null);
            txt = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.text_name)
            layout.setTag(this);
        }

        public void update(String s) {
        txt.setText(s);
        }

        public LinearLayout getView() {
        return layout;
        }
    }

}
```

And the item layout

```
<LinearLayout
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:orientation="horizontal" >

     <TextView
          android:id="@+id/text_name"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

With this code you only need to change the ItemHolder and it's xml file to make it look more like what you want. The setTag() and getTag() are used to reuse the views and makes it more efficient.

Note that Android L pronounced new widgets for this but it's not supported yet.
https://developer.android.com/preview/material/ui-widgets.html